# How to set up `xdg-open` to use Nautilus for `gvfs` paths?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, google-chrome, xdg-open

`xdg-open /run/user/1000/gvfs/ftp:host=smart,port=5555,user=u` runs `chrome`.

How to make it run `nautilus` instead?

Answer (score 1):

From `man xdg-open`

> xdg-open opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application. If a URL is provided the URL will be opened in the user's preferred web browser.
> ...
> xdg-open supports `file`, `ftp`, `http` and `https` URLs.

The [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/xdg-open.1.html) states that as long as the target is a recognized URL it will always use a web browser.  This looks like what you want is not possible
<sub>(apart from registering nautilus as your favourite web browser whis is a bad idea™ )</sub>